# Platform field value isnt updating in Document Level through Junction Object

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

Object structure:

```
 #Platform
 #JunctionPlatformDoc (junction object)
 #Document
```

Platform contains its name and aircraft manufacture sosl field. I have to populate those fields in document Level, In case of platform Update.

```
For example: Document 1 link to {platform1 ,platform 2}

Platform1-> aircraftmanufature: new  platformname:platform1
Platform 2--> aircraftmanufature:old  platformname:platform2

Document1: platformsosl:platform1,platform 2
            aircraftmanufature sosl:new,old
```

---

```
trigger s360_PlatformSOSLTrigger on Platform__c (after Update) {
 if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
  S360_PlatformDetails.platformUpdate(trigger.new);
  }
```

---

```
public class S360_PlatformDetails {
public static void platformUpdate(List<Platform__c> platformList){
set<id> platformId=new set<id>();
    List<Document__c> doccumentList=new List<Document__c>();
    map<id,List<Platform__c>> docs=new map<id,List<Platform__c>>();


    for(Platform__c plat:platformList){
        platformId.add(plat.id);
    }

    List<JunctionPlatformDoc__c> junctions = [select Document__r.Name,Document__r.Description__c,Document__r.recordtypeId,Document__r.recordtype.name,Document__c,Platform__c,Platform__r.Name from JunctionPlatformDoc__c where Platform__c in:platformId];
    set<id> documentIds=new set<id>();
    for(JunctionPlatformDoc__c junction : junctions)
    {
        documentIds.add(junction.Document__c);
    }
    List<Document__c> doclist2=new List<Document__c>();
    List<Document__c>docList1=[select id,AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c,PlatformSOSL__c,(select id,Platform__c,Platform__r.name,Platform__r.Aircraft_Manufacturer__c  from JunctionPlatformDocs__r) from Document__c where id in:documentIds];

    for(Document__c dc:docList1){
        for(JunctionPlatformDoc__c d:dc.JunctionPlatformDocs__r){
            if(dc.AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c==null){

                dc.AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c=d.Platform__r.Aircraft_Manufacturer__c;
            }
            if(dc.AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c!=null){
                dc.AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c=dc.AircraftManufacturerSOSL__c+';'+d.Platform__r.Aircraft_Manufacturer__c;

            }
            if(dc.PlatformSOSL__c==null){
                dc.PlatformSOSL__c=d.Platform__r.name;
            }
            if(dc.PlatformSOSL__c!=null){
                dc.PlatformSOSL__c=dc.PlatformSOSL__c=+';'+d.Platform__r.name;
            }

            doclist2.add(dc);
        }
    }
    if(!doclist2.isEmpty()){
        update doclist2;

    }
}}
```

Comment: edit your question and specify where you are facing issues. Did you put proper debug log?

Comment: ya I edited the question and already put the debug log it shows null value

Comment: Actually if you check the code its incomplete there is an empty for loop which does nothing and `JunctionPlatformDoc__c` list that actually will have no values as `platformId` is an empty set

Comment: You really need to include a specific question with a description of the behavior. Saying "it doesn't work" or "it isn't updating" is rarely enough to properly identify a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`platformId` is empty.

You have just declared as `set<id> platformId=new set<id>();`

And you are using that in SOQL query, thats why it is not giving results.

Add values to `platformId` before executing SOQL.

Comment: sorry ..I have missed it..while adding the question..please check it now

Comment: you need to put step by step debugging to reach why it is giving null

Comment: Okay.Thanks Santanu..but still Issue is there suppose document1 link to {platform1 ,platform 2} its not working as expected